# Unexpected token: Error:(40, 61) error: illegal character: \8232 in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I copy paste code into Android Studio sometimes (from WEB or other external source) I get some unvisible characters and I can't compile. Is there a way to avoid this? Reformat code automatically? Plugin? Change settings?

```
Error:(40, 61) error: illegal character: \8232
```

So far I delete the code any type it in by hand again.

Comment: you could also copy and paste into a notepad (or notepad++) and then copy and paste into AS. But thats just a quick workaround and not a solution.

Comment: I did Transliterate selection to ASCII in TextMate.

Comment: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode

Answer (score 1):

I believe your file encoding is windows-1252 (bottom right corner in AS)?
Here is a Blog about file encoding. I also use UTF-8 for everything.
[Blog about file encodings in IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/)

Since AS is IntelliJ-based, this also applies to AS.

Answer (score 1):

**\8232** is decimal for **U+2028**

on a **Mac**, it usually gets into **IntelliJ/AndroidStudio** when text is copied and pasted from **Notes**

in **System Preferences**, open **Keyboard/Input Sources** and add **Unicode Hex Input**

in **IntelliJ/AndroidStudio**, open **Edit/Find/Replace** and type **2028** *while holding **Option** key*, then click **Replace all**

Comment: I couldn't find `Unicode Hex Input` on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I used this site (https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/), copied and pasted my code surrounding where the invisible error was, and pasted it into the top box right under the button "Convert."

Then I copied and pasted the result code that was automatically generated in the box under the title "Unicode U+hex notation", and noticed it had something like this:

```
//Remove the last 2 characters (The last ", ").
U+2028title.substring(0, title.length() - 2);
return title;
```

I just deleted the `U+2028` and pasted that code back into Android Studio, and it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

@Rock Lee

After you open

```
SystemPreferences>Keyboard>InputSources
```

- click the '+' icon, then in the Search box at the bottom enter
  "Unicode"

or

- scroll all the way to the bottom of the language list to 
  "Others", where it is listed as well.