# What does an unexpected token mean and can I solve it?

Tags: android, json, token, illegal-characters

Android Studio is telling me that there are some "Unexpected Tokens"..

**what are these??**

screenshots:

error in code
[image: where the error is]

error in Messages
[image: error:]

Comment: Did you copy/paste code from internet ? There may be some invisible characters.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the code? [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808561/unexpected-token-error40-61-error-illegal-character-8232-in-android-stud)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have invisible character in these lines, \8232 is line separator. Possibly you copied it somewhere.

Try to paste it in Notepad/TextEdit and copy text from there. Point is to get rid of formatting and extra characters. Or you can just delete these lines and retype them manually.

Comment: Thanks. I Remember i copied it from SubLime Editor - hence the formatting. 
It works now. :)

Comment: How to do this programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private InputStream checkForUtf8BOMAndDiscardIfAny(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
 PushbackInputStream pushbackInputStream = new PushbackInputStream(new 
 BufferedInputStream(inputStream), 3);
 byte[] bom = new byte[3];
 if (pushbackInputStream.read(bom) != -1) {
    if (!(bom[0] == (byte) 0xEF && bom[1] == (byte) 0xBB && bom[2] == (byte) 0xBF)) {
        pushbackInputStream.unread(bom);
    }
 }
 return pushbackInputStream; 
}
```