# Android manifest returns error: unexpected tokens

Tags: android, android-studio

My android manifest is returning an error: `unexpected tokens`. I can't fix it. Here is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" package="com.weblogtemplates.material" platformBuildVersionCode="22" platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="22" /><supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.weblogtemplates.material.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature|signatureOrSystem" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.weblogtemplates.material.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:debuggable="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:supportsRtl="true">
<activity
    android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/activity_name"
    android:name="com.weblogtemplates.material.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="10">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity
    android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
<activity
    android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"
    android:exported="true" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.weblogtemplates.material" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
</application></manifest>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you elaborate with a traceview? Just paste what error you get?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146115/what-means-unexpected-token-and-how-to-solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing unnecessary tags and invisible characters...
Took some time to figure out all :D

Answer (score 1):

You have got an * after the @ in the theme of your MainActivity and Adactivity

Answer (score 0):

Hi this could be an error caused by invisible character which has been copied while you tried to copy the code from somewhere else. Probably the internet.You can delete the line where the error is pointed to and re type the line. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the line used to set the theme.

It should be

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

not

```
android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```